# Linq To SQL delete a mapping object with dual primary keys

Tags: linq-to-sql

In Linq To SQL, how to delete a mapping object with dual primary keys?
If simply Remove() from EntitySet, SubmitChanges() fails

Comment: by 'dual', do you mean composite?

Comment: yes , it is composite PK

Comment: May be, there is some dependency with other table and hence  SaveChanges() method not worked.

Comment: An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a X and a Y. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (Y.ID) cannot be set to null.

Comment: Dealing with the same issue right now